# Issue with Google Script Clashing With QUERY Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a sheet with is collecting form responses. I'm then using the QUERY function to pull all the data into a separate sheet to action using the following formula:

```
=QUERY(formsubmissions,"SELECT *")
```

where `formsubmissions` in the Named Range.

Once four steps have taken place the user then selects Completed = Ýes' which triggers the following script:

```
function onEdit() {


 var sheetNameToWatch = "R+R;

 var columnNumberToWatch = 15;

 var valueToWatch = "Yes";

 var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Completed";



 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

 var range = sheet.getActiveCell();



 if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);

   var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);

   sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);

   sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());

 }

}
```

This script executes and functions correctly, moving the row into the `Çompleted` sheet and deleting from the active sheet. However, the row is only momentarily deleted and appears back almost instantaneously. I guess this is because it still matches the QUERY parameters so it is pulled in again straight away.

How can I ensure it stays deleted either by modifying the query or by modifying the script?

Answer (score 0):

As you've surmised, this occurs because the row in the original responses sheet still fulfils the query criteria. You could modify your query to exclude any unique identifiers by checking that it doesn't already appear in the Completed sheet - Say that column A is a reference number or timestamp, you could try the following:

```
=QUERY(formsubmissions,"SELECT * where A <> "&Completed!A:A)
```

This then checks the array in Completed A:A for the same value, and excludes it from the query result if present.